# Корректное предоставление доступа к массиву ключ-значение

Tags: c++, ооп, проектирование

Сразу предупреждаю, тема вопроса может показаться странной , т.к. речь идет о "вкусовщине".

Имеется файл определённого формата, я создаю класс, коотрый читает этот файл и записывает в объект значения из него. В данном файле записаны имена и значения некоторых констант и мне требуется предоставить к ним доступ через интерфейс класса. В общем, проблемы в этом никакой нет, однако я не знаю как это сделать удобным для пользователя. 
На данном этапе я переложил всё на самого пользователя, то есть даю доступ к массиву с именами и массиву со значениями по-отдельности. Так же я предоставляю функцию поиска значения константы по её имени. 
И всё-таки мне кажется, что такой интерфейс не очень лаконичен, что ли и хотелось бы иметь более элегантное решение предоставления доступа к константам.
Я думал использовать std::map и возвращать его по константной ссылке через геттер, но синтаксически это выглядит не очень красиво, как мне кажется.
В общем, как бы вы организовали доступ к хранящимся массивам с именами и значениями констант (с учетом того, что пользователю захочется получить список имен хранимых констант и желательно в порядке их хранения в файле)?

Comment: Почему вы не хотите использовать map? Если вложенность отсутствует, то это лучший способ в данной ситуации.

Comment: Используйте map, или оставьте два массива, как есть, только их обрабатывать сложнее. Но ни в том ни в другом случае не предоставляйте доступ к ним пользователю. Скройте внутреннее представление, а пользователю дайте набор функций для доступа на чтение, если надо - на запись, функции поиска и т.п.